# concurrency | goroutines | golang | buffered reader

Tags: go, concurrency, udp, bufferedreader

**Believe** I am either misunderstanding how go routines work, how buffered readers work or both.

**Expect** an asynchronous execution of the goroutine ( a buffered reader with a for loop reading the buffer, waiting for a message from the server )

**Try** `METHOD A` to call `go xyz()` before the client dials the server; so `xyz()` creates the buffer and starts reading in the background. Then, the client dials the server; server sends message back; the client is reading the buffer so, it gets the message and prints to console

**What Actually Happens** the client to send the message to the server, but does not pick up anything on the buffer while reading for possible reply from server; so it is running concurrently because I know the for loop has not stopped, but it lets the next line of code execute ( client sending message to server ).

**But When** `METHOD B` I call `xyz()` NOT concurrently and after the client dials the server, all things work as expected. The client gets the message back from the server and prints to console.

---

**METHOD A**, we have the order :

***/////////////*** steps 1 and 2 are in the goroutine called by `go xyz()`

1. creates the buffered reader
2. for loop -- reading the buffer for message from the server -- print out
3. client dials the server

   `go xyz(conn, p)`

   `fmt.Fprintf(conn, "Give me a hash to work on ...")`

---

**METHOD B**, we have the order :

***/////////////*** steps 2 and 3 are in the goroutine called by `xyz()`

1. client dials the server
2. creates buffered reader
3. for loop -- reading the buffer for message from the server -- print out

   `fmt.Fprintf(conn, "Give me a hash to work on ...")`

   `xyz(conn, p)`

---

---

---

**client.go**

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "bufio"
)

func xyz(conn net.Conn, p []byte) {
  rd := bufio.NewReader(conn)
  for {
    _, err := rd.Read(p)
    if err == nil {
      fmt.Printf("SERVER : %s\n", p)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Some error %v\n", err)
    }
  }
}

func main() {
    p :=  make([]byte, 2048)
    conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "127.0.0.1:1234")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Some error %v", err)
        return
    }

    go xyz(conn, p)
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "Give me a hash to work on ...")
}
```

---

**server.go**

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)


func sendResponse(conn *net.UDPConn, addr *net.UDPAddr, hash string) {
    _,err := conn.WriteToUDP([]byte("Hello, here is the hash  - " + hash), addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Couldn't send response %v", err)
    }
}


func main() {
    hash := "36";
    p := make([]byte, 2048)
    addr := net.UDPAddr{
        Port: 1234,
        IP: net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1"),
    }
    ser, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Some error %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    for {
        _, remoteaddr, err := ser.ReadFromUDP(p)
        fmt.Printf("CLIENT : %v : %s\n", remoteaddr, p)
        if err !=  nil {
            fmt.Printf("Some error  %v", err)
            continue
        }
        go sendResponse(ser, remoteaddr, hash)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Go statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)
>
> A "go" statement starts the execution of a function call as an
>   independent concurrent thread of control, or goroutine, within the
>   same address space.
>
> ... unlike with a regular call, program execution does not wait for
>   the invoked function to complete.

`client.go` starts the goroutine `xyz` and then keeps going to the end of the `main` function which terminates the program. The program doesn't wait for the `xyz` goroutine to run or finish.

Comment: So you are implying that the buffered reader does not have time to start up before the client receives message back from server?

Comment: I tried `time.Sleep(2000)` after goroutine and before sending message to server. Still did not work.

Comment: @MattClendenen: I'm saying that `xyx` didn't get very far before `main` ended and the program, and therefore `xyx`, terminated.

Comment: `time.Sleep(5000)` after client sends message to server is what made it work. You were right, needed time to read / output.

Comment: @MattClendenen: A [Duration](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) represents the elapsed time between two instants as an int64 nanosecond count. You slept for 2000 nanoseconds. Try something longer: `time.Sleep(60*time.Second)`.